# Nunit - How to get all test lines (written in test ) before execution (in c#)

Tags: c#, nunit, nunit-3.0, nunit-2.5

Below is Nunit test.I want to get all test lines before test execution.

```
public void Test01()
{
abc = 1;
pqr();
xyz();
lmn = 9;
zxy();
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "getting" test lines? Which line is the "test execution"?

Comment: you want to read the lines of code as a string? why?

Comment: getting means, I want to read all lines, depending on those lines, I have to set up few things at run time.

Comment: You can in principle decompile the method at run time and e.g. react on called methods. Not easy, but possible. I would recommend looking for other options first.